# How to read properties of a document(Doc,Docx,XLS,XLSX) without using Interop as Office is not installed

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, sharepoint, office-interop

How Can i read properties for example Title,Author of a document (doc,docx,ppt,pptx..) without using Microsoft.Office.Interop as Office is not installed in the pc

Comment: If you can't use Office then the office-interop tag is not appropriate for this question...

Comment: The alternative to reading documents in an Office application is to read the information directly from the files. This is no problem for the dotx, pptx since the Office Open XML file formats were designed expressly for this purpose. It's well-documented and there are tools to aid you, such as the Open XML SDK. The old, binary file formats aren't as easy to access, although there are third-party libraries available to read them. Other than that, you can obtain the specification to write your own "reader": http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc313105.aspx.

Comment: Also for the old binary file format there's an old tool, dsoFile.exe, that can access the document properties. It's no longer supported, so YMMV but here are the relevant links https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/224351, https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8422, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsod/archive/2012/10/20/considerations-when-using-dsofile-on-64-bit-operating-systems.aspx